# Installation of ruby-1.9.3-p392 using rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have installed rvm and my project requires `ruby-1.9.3-p392`. I installed `ruby-1.9.3-p392` and changed the version using:

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p392
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p392
```

But when I close terminal it set to ruby `2.3.0p0` by default and every time I need to run

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p392
```

Please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Set rvm to default by using `--default` flag

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p392 --default
```

**NOTE:** You might need to close and open the terminal.

Type `rvm` for usage details

```
== Flags
--default  :: with 'rvm use X', sets the default ruby for new shells to X.
```

**Solution 2**

Create `.ruby-version` file in your project with the following content

*.ruby-version*

```
1.9.3-p392
```

This will change the ruby version to use `1.9.3-p392` automatically whenever you enter in project directory

Comment: Still not working I am facing same issue. when I check version after closing terminal `ruby -v` it showing ruby-2.3.0

Comment: Thanks Deepak! second solution works! I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

try `rvm use --ruby-version <ruby version>@global`

Comment: close and reopen the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Set your ruby version default in rvm :

```
  rvm --default use <your ruby version>
```

For more refer: https://rvm.io/rubies/default